# How can I set chart XValue and YValue members from dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

I trying to set chart XValueMember and YValueMember from dictionary collection:

```
public partial class GraphWindow : Window
{
   Dictionary<int, double> value;
    public GraphWindow(Dictionary<int, double> values)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        value = new Dictionary<int, double>(values);
        Plot();
    }

    public void Plot()
    {
        Chart chart = this.FindName("Chart") as Chart;
        if (chart != null)
        {
            chart.DataSource = value;
            chart.Series["series"].XValueMember = "Key";
            chart.Series["series"].YValueMembers = "Value";
        }
    }
}
```

The axis is built, but it is empty ([screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90254390/Capture1.PNG)). Previously, I tried to use KeyValuePair, but chart does not support it. How can I get values and keys from dictionary in chart format? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing just one tiny [piece](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.databind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the puzzle:

```
chart.DataSource = value;
chart.Series[0].XValueMember = "Key";
chart.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Value";
chart.DataBind();
```

The last line will establish the `DataBinding` after the others have set it up.

You will need to call it again whenever your data have changed..

Note: according to the MSDN link above..:

> In cases where a data source is set to a chart and no other data
>   operations are required, the DataBind method does not have to be
>   explicitly called. In these cases, the Chart itself will data bind to
>   the data source prior to being rendered.

.. and indeed you can enforce a rendering instead by calling

```
chart.Refresh();
```

But as the dictionary needs the setting of the value members **something** seems to be necessary to make it work..

Using these data

```
value.Clear();
value.Add(1,12);
value.Add(2,32);
value.Add(3,52);
value.Add(6,42);
```

this chart results:

[image]

Comment: Tried. Unfortunately, nothing happend. I think is because it takes only the last value in the dictionary. And chart becomes a point?

Comment: No, it takes all entries in the dictionary and each is shown as a datapoint here. See my edit! What are your values? Or maybe I should ask: Where do you actually add any data??

Comment: It is very strange. If I initialize the dictionary in this class the graph is built successfully. And if I pass dictionary through class constructor - does not work.

Comment: I'm adding data to dictionary in MainWindow class. Here is this class [code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90254390/mainWindow.txt)

Comment: Not sure if your link is complete; there is no calls afaics

Comment: I probably understood the problem. Dictionary in my class stores only last added key\value pair. But not all. Previous values are lost...Don't know why